# Call a function with its parameters from a stack frame based on EBP in c

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, x86

I have read [Extended Asm - Assembler Instructions with C Expression Operands](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html#Extended-Asm) and [A side-by-side look at GNU Assembler (GAS) and Netwide Assembler (NASM)](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/l-gas-nasm/index.html), but some problems cannot be resolved yet.

Well, I dynamically designed a piece of code.

```
; int xx_method_stub(void *fix_arg1, void* fix_arg2, void* arg3)
push  ebp                   ; 55
mov   ebp, esp              ; 89 E5
sub   esp, imm8_local_size  ; 83 EC imm8_local_size
mov   [ebp-4], imm_ptr_mid  ; C7 45 FC imm_ptr_mid
jmp   rel16_offset          ; E9 rel16_offset
```

See details about it [here](http://ideone.com/a0RLAU), maybe a little too much.

And now it jumps to a well-designed address, the stack frame context is as following:

```
16(%ebp)  - third function parameter
12(%ebp)  - second function parameter
 8(%ebp)  - first function parameter
 4(%ebp)  - old %EIP (the function's "return address")
 0(%ebp)  - old %EBP (previous function's base pointer)
-4(%ebp)  - first local variable
```

So far, I want need a jmp label code in `c`.

```
void stubthunk_init(stubthunk *stub, mid_t mid) {
    memcpy(stub, &stubthunk_templet, sizeof(stubthunk));
    stub->ph_mid = mid;
    stub->ph_eip_to_dispatch = (int) ((uintptr_t) dispatch - ((uintptr_t) stub + sizeof(stubthunk)));

// TODO retrieve stack variables as c-syntax local variables to make a function call in c for for portability.
//stack frame context
void *param_1; // 8(%%ebp)
void* param_2; //12(%%ebp)
void* local_1; //-4(%%ebp)

    disp:

#ifdef _MSC_VER
    __asm {
        mov param_1 [ebp+8]
        mov param_2 [ebp+12]
        mov local_1 [ebp-4]
    }
#else
    __asm__ __volatile(
        "mov 8(%%ebp), %0\n\t"
        "mov 12(%%ebp), %1\n\t"
        "mov -4(%%ebp), %2\n\t"
        :"=m" (param_1), "=m" (param_2), "=m" (local_1)
        :
        : /* clobbered register.  */
    );
#endif
    //USE #param_1 to restore or blance the stack
}
```

### So

Are there some way to get it that **get jmp code block in c** and retrieve stack variables as c-syntax local variables to make a function call in `c` in order that I don't have to write more code in `asm`, in which case, regardless of the function calling conventions, the complier does help me on such as, arm, x86, x64, ...

I expect that I can set up the stack frame for a function [prologue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_prologue) and epilogue in `c` by myself. In this way, I can retrofit a function into a jmp code blok and balance the stack manually in my own way.

Or, like in masm, there is a persudo-directive `invoke`, e.g. `invoke MessageBox, NULL, addr MsgBoxText, addr MsgBoxCaption, MB_OK`, but it just exists in masm.

**=========Updated===========**

My target:

```
static native int foo(int otherArgsMaybeExist);
int stdcall Java_xx_foo(void *fixedArgEnv, void *fixedArgCls, jint otherArgsMaybeExist){
    return 0;
}

// TODO release stubthunk *stub
stubthunk *stub = (stubthunk*) alloc_code(sizeof(stubthunk));
stubthunk_init(stub, (intptr_t) argsize);
```

Now, I dynamically create a `stdcall` function start code in memory, which 
should be as little as possible except of some necessary data(here pass a jmethodID so as to make the followed `interpret_stdcall_x86` know who is called).

After registering with `stub` for a java method with the native modifier, and entries the native world, it will go into my code. In fact, it's a trampoline like Detours on Windows.

After jumping, all intercepted method will entry `interpret_stdcall_x86`, 
which is responsible for the stack blance.

It's original like this:

```
foo -> Java_xx_foo -> return
```

Now, will be like:

```
foo -> stubthunk + interpret_stdcall_x86 + blance the stack -> return
```

Here, `thubthunk` is hard-code but created dynamically using instructions. Whereas, I expect I can code using `c` for interpret_stdcall_x86.

**===========================**

- [Intel x86 Function-call Conventions - Assembly View](http://unixwiz.net/techtips/win32-callconv-asm.html)
- [GNU Mixed Language Programming: Calling Conventions](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gnat_ugn/Calling-Conventions.html)
- [Wiki: Calling convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calling_convention)
- [invoke MessageBox](http://win32assembly.programminghorizon.com/tut2.html)

Comment: [6.44.5.2 Specifying Registers for Local Variables](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-6.1.0/gcc/Local-Register-Variables.html#Local-Register-Variables)

Comment: `jmp   rel16_offset`???  in 32 or 64bit code, your only options are [rel8 and rel32](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/JMP.html).  Of course, the assembler takes care of this for you.  Using an operand-size prefix to get the rel16 encoding also masks EIP with `0x0000FFFF`.

Comment: So you're trying to jump into the middle of a C function, from asm?  It's not clear what you're gaining by using asm at all.  Why can't you just write a wrapper function in C to manipulate the args and call another function?  Or from asm, tail-call a C function through its normal entry-point (with args in their usual place as per the calling convention).

Comment: I"m not 100% clear what you're looking for, but [GCC's builtins for constructing function calls](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Constructing-Calls.html) seem like they might be relevant.

Comment: Helpful~ I will try it  the next thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to put a jump target inside a function body, you can just use `asm volatile (".globl my_label\n"  "my_label:" );` and jump there from asm.

You shouldn't expect this to work, though.

The compiler's choice of how to build a stack frame will depend on the optimization level, and inlining, so there's no safe way to write asm that matches the epilogue of whatever function you want to jump into.

---

### It's not clear what the purpose of all this is, and why you can't just do it with C.

---

The inline-asm you show is broken:

```
__asm__ __volatile(
    "mov 8(%%ebp), %0\n\t"   // mov mem,mem  isn't valid.
    "mov 12(%%ebp), %1\n\t"
    "mov -4(%%ebp), %2\n\t"
    :"=m" (param_1), "=m" (param_2), "=m" (local_1)
     // instead, use "=r" constraints to have the outputs in registers
     // from there, the compiler will put them where it wants them
    :
    : /* clobbered register.  */
);
```

I don't see how it makes sense to load the args from the stack from inline asm yourself.  Why not just use function args so the compiler knows what's going on?

Comment: Indeed, you are right. I just cannot help expecting that a c local variable can attach a register or stack, and detach.

Comment: Because there are multiple files, I created a github test [repository](https://github.com/ssfang/dynative/tree/devel/native), while ideone cannot do that.